# How to make subversion to ignore a sub directory, although it is defined in the properties via propedit?

Tags: svn

In `svn` version 1.7.9 I am trying to ignore a directory in subversion. I have tried to insert the following line into the editor popping up when calling

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

Here is the first attempt:

```
addons/pnc_tests/utils_mod
```

And here is the second attempt:

```
utils_mod addons/pnc_tests
```

But in both cases `svn st` gives the following output:

```
?       addons/pnc_tests/utils_mod
```

So what text do I have to put into the `propedit` file in order to ignore that directory? Just adding filenames in the propedit file works fine, those are being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only *ignore* the immediate subdirectory. To do what you want, you have to attach the `svn:ignore` to the `addons/pnc_tests` directory itself:

```
$ cd addons/pnc_tests
$ svn ps svn:ignore utils_mods .   # Better using `pe` if there's more than one ignore
```

Of course, the old caveat that you cannot ignore an already added in file still applies (although in your question, it doesn't look like this is an issue).

Subversion 1.8 introduces [inheritable properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.inheritable) which might be more what you want. Inheritable properties means that a file or directory in a directory subtree *inherits* the property from a tree ancestor. Two inheritable properties are `svn:global-ignores` and `svn:autoprops`. These act very similarly to these settings in the user's Subversion configuration file -- except can be applied to the whole repository.

Imagine you could do something like this:

```
$ svn ps svn:global-ignores "*test*" .
```

And any directory or file in the entire file tree with `test` in the name will be ignored.